# Nifi InvokeHTTP processor stop and show invalid Type

Tags: apache-nifi

I am a newbie in using Apache Nifi. I have an issue when using InvokeHTTP processor to call a rest API. After i view NiFi Data Provenance of this processor. I see Type column of this processor was changed to "ATTRIBUTES_MODIFIED" and stucked at this processor. As I know Type of InvokeHTTP processor only: DROP, FETCH, FORK.

[image: Type of InvokeHttp was changed]

This issue will be resolved if I restart Nifi service. However after a duration time (4 to 5 hours), this issue will happen again.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: `As i know Type of InvokeHTTP processor only: DROP, FETCH, FORK.` - Any documentation ref for that? ATTRIBUTES_MODIFIED happens on attribute modify on original file. And that could be caused by error or retry. Please edit the question and add outputs of processor.

Comment: @daggett Thanks for your reply. 
Because I track provenance data i see the most of type of InvokeHTTP in DROP, FETCH, FORK  but I think you are right. Type in provenance was defined in here https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.nifi/nifi-api/1.6.0/org/apache/nifi/provenance/ProvenanceEventType.html
Can you show me how to check what attribute were modified in processor ?

Answer (score 0):

ATTRIBUTES_MODIFIED happens on attribute modify on original file. And that could be caused by error or retry.

Check the `Relationships` and `Writes Attributes` section in InvokeHTTP documentation: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.23.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html

To see attributes changed in `Data Provenance` - click the `(i)` icon on a record and then `Show modified attributes only`

[image]